# Rails: Assigning Variables to Associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey I am trying to assign my currentslide that is part of my courses model and is associated to my user model.

I have 3 models: 
- Users
- Courses (title: ,currentprogress: )
- UserCourseAssignment. (association table)

I can get the courses that a user has been assigned by typing User.courses however it won't let me update variables

```
#<Course id: 6, title: "beginnerscourse", created_at: "2016-03-20 12:42:44",   
updated_at: "2016-03-20 12:42:44", reward1: nil, reward2: nil, reward3: nil,   
reward4: nil, reward5: nil, currentslide: 0, totalslides: nil>]> 

User = active_user   
User.courses.find(6).currentslide = 1 
User.save
```

Sorry if I wasnt clear, Updated question

Comment: Don't assign a class name as a variable. use `user` or just use `active_user`. ex: `active_user.courses.find(6).update_attributes(currentslide: 1)`

Comment: You want to update `currentslide` to 1?

Comment: Hey thanks Justin that is working for me. Sorry Pavan I wasn't clear and updated the question for anybody else. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't assign a class name (`User`) as a variable. In your scenario, you can just use `active_user`.

```
active_user.courses.find(6).update_attributes(current_slide: 1)
```

As I was writing a better explanation as to why, @max answered as well with a great explanation as to what is going on here. Please refer to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36115979/2456549) for a great explanation.

He is also correct in reference to just using `Course.find`, if you already know the course ID. There is no need to load all of the current_user's courses from the DB if you already know the ID. You'll get better performance just using `Course.find(id).update_attributes...`

Comment: Hey. What is the exact reason behind this. I used to learn from udemy and didn't realise it is bad practise. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @max explained it well.

Answer (score 2):

```
User = active_user   
User.courses.find(6).currentslide = 1 
User.save
```

There are quite a few things going wrong here. `User` declares a constant which will mask your `User` class! In Ruby any identifier which starts with an uppercase letter is a constant.

Watch this example:

```
User = active_user   
# somewhere else in the code
User.find(5) # NoMethodError wtf!?
```

Also if you know the id of the course there is no need to go through the user in the first place:

```
course = Course.find(6)
course.update_attributes(currentslide: 1)
```

If you want to scope the query to the current user as poor mans version of access controller you would do it like so:

```
course = Course.where(user: current_user).find(6)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Those first 2 examples make a lot of sense. Had not thought about that. However in the third example if I would just say Course.find and update an attribute without going through user this would change all the courses with the id of 6 right? The main goal is to track on what slide of each course the users are. Again thank you so much for your time and effort!

Comment: "this would change all the courses with the id of 6 right?" - well unless you are doing something totally crazy the `id` attribute is unique and generated by the database. So there can only be one Course with the id 6 - ever.